# Number Theory: Prove that there are two different permutations $a, b$ which $n! \ | \ S(a)-S(b)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Assume $n$ is an integer which is odd and $n > 1$. We have function
>   $S(a)$ which $a$ is a permutation of numbers $\{1,2 \ldots ,n\}$  and $S(a) =
> > c_1a_1 + c_2a_2 + ... + c_na_n$ ($c_i$'s are all constants)
>
> Prove that there are two different permutations $a, b$ which:
>
> $n! \ | \ S(a)-S(b)$

How can i prove this statement?

Comment: Hint: if $c_i\equiv c_j \pmod n$, interchanging $a_i$ and $a_j$. So WLOG we may assume $c_i = i - 1$. Now note that $0\times 3+1\times 1 + 2\times 2 = 0\times 2+1\times 3+2\times 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $c_1,...,c_n$ are integers, and $n>1$ is an odd integer.

Let $P$ be the set of all permutations of $\{1,...n\}$.

The claim is that there exist distinct $a,b \in P\,$ such that $n!\mid (S(a)-S(b))$.

Suppose instead that no such pair $a,b$ exists.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Let $x = {\displaystyle{\sum_{p \in P}S(p)}}$. Then by symmetry,

\begin{align*}
x &= (c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n)\,\bigl((n-1)!\bigr)\,(1 + 2 + \cdots + n)\\[4pt]
&= (c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n)\,\bigl((n-1)!\bigr)\!
\left(
{\small{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}
\right)\\[4pt]
&= (c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n)\,(n!)\left({\small{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\right)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

hence $x \equiv 0 \pmod{n!}$.

But by assumption, if $a,b \in P$ with $a \ne b$, then $S(a) \not\equiv S(b) \pmod{n!}$,
hence 
$$\{S(p)\;\text{mod}\;n!\} = \{0,1,2,...,n!-1\}$$

Let $w = n!/2.\;\,$Then

\begin{align*}
&x \equiv 0 \pmod{n!}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &0 + 1 + 2  + \cdots + (n!-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{n!}\\[4pt]
\implies\;  &0 + (1 + (n! - 1)) + (2 + (n! - 2)) + \cdots + ((w-1) + (w+1)) + w  \equiv 0 \pmod{n!}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &w  \equiv 0 \pmod{n!}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

contradiction, since $0 < w < n!$.

The contradiction proves the claim.